# why write() executes before printf()? Is not it supposedly sequential?

Tags: c, printf, sequential

this is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void main(){
    char str1[18]= "moo\0 cuek\n";
    printf("lel: %s",str1);

    write(STDOUT_FILENO,str1,18);
    write(STDOUT_FILENO,"meow ",19);

}
```

and the output is:

```
moo cuek
meow moo cuek
lel:moo
```

also, why is `meow` printed first and then `moo cuek` (second line)

P.S. when I put `\n` inside printf like:

```
printf("lel: %s \n",str1);
```

I get:

```
lel:moo
moo cuek
meow moo cuek
```

Why?!

Comment: Hint: what is 'buffered IO'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here

```
printf("lel: %s",str1);
```

`printf()` prints the data on file stream where its points and default it is `stdout` stream and `stdout` stream is line buffered i.e you need to flush the buffer by calling `fflush(stdout)`or adding `\n` char. For e.g

```
printf("lel: %s",str1);
fflush(stdout);
```

or

```
printf("lel: %s\n",str1); /* newline char has another use apart from giving newline i.e clear the buffer */
```

Or you can disable the buffering by calling `setbuf()`.

while here

```
 write(STDOUT_FILENO,str1,18);
```

`write()` is a system call which is not buffered IO i.e it doesn't buffer the data, hence it immediately write the data into `STDOUT_FILENO`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the details, but basically most functions that write to the console are buffered.  That means when you call the function is not necessarily when the text gets printed.
See:
[Why does printf not flush after the call unless a newline is in the format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin)